# How to cancel the current dialog of a bot after a timeout (BotBuilder-Js)

Tags: javascript, botframework

I am trying to cancel an ongoing dialog if a user does not respond for some time.
As far as I'm aware, there are no built in methods for this

However, everytime I call for DialogContext.cancelAllDialogs(), I receive this error:[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQEwx.png)